# Moving player left and right (touchesbegan)

Tags: sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I have a toon (player.physicsbody) which I want to move left and right by pressing two buttons (like a ship in Space Invaders). I have coded this and it works ok, the problem comes when I run the app in a device, if "left button" is pressed, pressing "right button" does nothing and viceversa.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"rightbutton"]){

        player.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(200, player.physicsBody.velocity.dy);

    }

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"leftbutton"]){

        player.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(-200, player.physicsBody.velocity.dy);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to allow the user to press both buttons at the same time?

Comment: Yes. I have multitouch enabled and it doesn't work. Press left, move left, press right, move right. Problem is if you quickly press left, right, left, right, the player gets stacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [event allTouches] returns an NSSet of UITouch events. Calling [[event allTouches] anyObject] returns only one member of that set. I modified your code to iterate over all touches in the set.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in [event allTouches]) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"rightbutton"]){

            player.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(200, player.physicsBody.velocity.dy);

        }
        else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"leftbutton"]){

            player.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(-200, player.physicsBody.velocity.dy);

        }
    }
}
```